# $\forall x \in Fix( \sigma ),\ \mathcal{O}(x)=\{ x\} $ and $\forall x \in supp( \sigma ), \{ x\}\subset \mathcal{O}(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

> Let $\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_{n}$ 
>   Show that :
>   $$\forall x \in \operatorname{Fix}( \sigma ),\ \mathcal{O}(x)=\{ x\} \quad \rm{ and }\quad \forall x \in \operatorname{supp}( \sigma ),\ \{ x\}\subset \mathcal{O}(x)$$

- $\mathcal{O}(x)=\{\sigma(x)^{k}\mid \ k\in \mathbb{Z}  \}$: The orbit of $x$ on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$
- $\operatorname{Fix}(\sigma)=\{k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\ \mid \  \sigma(k)=k \}$ set of fixed point
- $\operatorname{Supp}(\sigma)=\{ k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\ \mid \  \sigma(k)\neq k  \}$ set of support of $\sigma$
- $\subset$ strict or proper inclusion

Indeed,
as you said by knowing that $\sigma(x) = x$
I'll show that $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}\ , \sigma^{n}(x)=x$

- Let P(n) be the statement

  $$\sigma^n(x) = x $$
- Basis: $P(1)$ asserts that $\sigma(x) = x$  this is true.
- Inductive step: Assume $P(n)$. We prove $P(n + 1)$
  Note that $P(n + 1)$ is the statement  $\sigma^{n+1}(x)=x$

\begin{aligned}
\sigma^{n+1}(x)&=(\sigma^{n}\circ  \sigma)(x)\\
&=\sigma^{n}(\sigma(x) )\\
&=\sigma^{n}(x) \\
&=x \mbox{ Induction hypothesis }\\
\sigma^{n+1}(x)&=x
\end{aligned}
Thus, $P(n)$ implies $P(n + 1)$, so the result is true by induction.

- Let $x\in \operatorname{supp}(\sigma) \mbox{ then } \sigma(x)\neq x $ thus

Reference:

[Book-page 225_Example_10-8](https://books.google.fr/books?id=x9Ml5YRIeEgC&hl=fr&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

[image]

Comment: Your definition of the [orbit](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupOrbit.html) $\mathcal O(x)$ is incorrect. It is the set of all elements that $x$ is mapped to by the permutations in the group acting on the set. If the group is $\frak S_n$ and the set is $\{1, \ldots, n \}$, then the orbit of each element in the set is the whole set (the action is transitive).

Comment: The question, as it is written, is incorrect (the stated conclusions do not follow from the given conditions). Are you sure the group is the symmetric group $\frak S_n$ and not the cyclic group of "rotations" of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ or something? If the latter, then $\mathcal O(x) = \{\, \sigma^k (x) \mid k \in \mathbb Z \,\}$, provided $\sigma$ is a generator of the group (notice the difference between this and what you wrote).

Comment: Okay, may I ask which book this is from?

Comment: Sorry but the assertions after "Indeed," are not even syntactically correct. What could $$x \in \mathcal{O}(x) \iff \exists k\in \mathbb{Z}\ \mid \ \sigma(x)^{k}$$ even *mean*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you have written does not make sense.

The formula $x \in \mathcal{O}(x) \iff \exists k=1 \mbox{ with } \sigma(x)=x$ is meaningless and/or false (and it's probably not what you wanted to write). Right now, in plain English, it means

> $x$ is in the orbit of $x$ if and only if there exists $k=1$ such that $\sigma(x) = x$.

I see that you're using a French book, so maybe a French translation will help too:

> $x$ est dans l'orbite de $x$ si et seulement si il existe $k = 1$ tel que $\sigma(x) = x$.

The "there exists $k=1$" part is meaningless, so the formula cannot be true as it's not even syntactically correct.

Let's assume that by this you mean "there exists $k$ such that $k = 1$ and $\sigma(x) = x$". Okay, but what's the purpose of the $k$? It does not appear in the subsequent formula. Besides, this is now false (an improvement over "meaningless"): $x$ is always in $\mathcal{O}(x)$, but it's not always true that $\sigma(x) = x$.

No, you need to go back to the basics. You have your assumption: $\sigma(x) = x$. You want to prove that $\mathcal{O}(x) = x$. So what you do is you take some $y \in \mathcal{O}(x)$, and you show that $y$ must be $x$. By definition of $\mathcal{O}(x)$, there exists $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $y = \sigma^k(x)$

But you know that $\sigma(x) = x$. By induction you can then prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\sigma^n(x) = x$ (do this, it's not as easy as it looks). It then follows that $y = \sigma^k(x) = x$. This prove $\mathcal{O}(x) \subseteq \{x\}$. Conversely, $x \in \mathcal{O}(x)$, because $x = \sigma^0(x)$. It follows that $\mathcal{O}(x) = \{x\}$.

---

For the second question, it's not really better. I honestly cannot make heads or tails of what you have written. Let me translate that to English, then tell me if this is what you wanted to write:

> $x$ belongs to $\{x\}$, hence there exists an integer $k \neq 1$ such that $\sigma^k(x) = x$, and therefore $x$ in the orbit of $x$. It follows that the set $\{x\}$ is strictly contained in the orbit of $x$.

This doesn't exactly read like a sound mathematical proof.

You want to prove that if $x \in \operatorname{supp}(x)$, then $\{x\} \subset \mathcal{O}(x)$. We already saw before that $x$ is always in $\mathcal{O}(x)$, so $\{x\} \subseteq \mathcal{O}(x)$ is OK. You want to show the inclusion is proper, so you need to exhibit an explicit element of $\mathcal{O}(x)$ that is not equal to $x$.

But your hypothesis was $x \in \operatorname{supp}(x)$, i.e. $\sigma(x) \neq x$. You know that $\sigma(x) = \sigma^1(x)$ is by definition in $\mathcal{O}(x)$. So there you go: $\sigma(x)$ in an element of the orbit of $x$, and it's not equal to $x$, hence the inclusion $\{x\} \subset \mathcal{O}(x)$ is proper.

Comment: If I may be so bold, you should stop treating mathematical formulas as magical formulas where you need to put together a few symbols in a random order and hope you get proof. The formulas actually mean something and follow a precise grammar.

Comment: Good explanation.really helpful. thanks  so much